# How do I speed up load times for Sencha Touch

Tags: sencha-touch-2, cloud9-ide

I am currently developing a Sencha Touch application using Cloud 9 IDE. I created the app on my local machine and later imported the project to Cloud 9. Everything works fine but an annoyance that happens is the load times for my page are greater than a minute. I think it has to do with all the files that are being individually loaded.

What is the best way to speed up the sdk load times? I am unsure how to use the sdk tools and do not know if you can even install them into Cloud 9. Would it be better to abandon the sdk tools and load Sencha manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Key is to minify & aggregate all the JS & CSS so that less number of bytes are transferred in less number of http calls. Sencha Cmd has the feature to do all this and create a packaged build to load fast, here is what you have to do from your app directory:

```
sencha app build package
```

This will create .>build>package folder with minified version of your app.

For more details read http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/guide/command and look at this http://vimeo.com/55148644 for illustration

Comment: Will this allow me to continue developing or will I have to keep repackaging?

Comment: It isn't stoping you from developing, do your dev and when you are ready to test/deploy package. Package folder need not to be checked in you can throw away old package before new package build

Comment: While doing this packaging did drastically improve my start up time. The inability to edit does not make this the solution I was hoping for. I would like to have a minified version of the touch sdk but expanded version of my code that doesn't require repackaging after editing.